# Отображение шрифтов в разных браузерах

Tags: html, css

[image: Внизу zeplin вверху firefox]Есть дизайн нарисованный в Zepplin. Там есть шрифт

```
font-family: HelveticaNeue;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #888888;
```

но почему то в браузере он отображается гораздо более худым чем в дизайне. в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Каждый браузер по своему рендерит шрифт, почитайте [это](https://szafranek.net/blog/2009/02/22/font-smoothing-explained/), так же попробуйте это: `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; ` ([в IE не работает](https://caniuse.com/#search=text-rendering))

Comment: Ну и для такого вопроса картинки бы не помешали

Comment: добавил картинку выше. там внизу zeplin вверху браузер

Answer (score 0):

Помогло поставить

```
font-weight: 600;
```

Потому что как я прочитал [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) если стоит `font-weight: 500;` будет отображаться шрифт обычного начертания. не жирный.

Comment: Правильно, хотя тут уже зависит от того, какой шрифт определите для `@font-face` с таким `font-weight`